# AWK positional variables processing

Tags: variables, awk, command, substitution

This my data from db

```
"1.1.1.1|1636057103"
```

How can i use something like `date +'%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S' -d @1636057103` inside AWK to convert unix timestamp in $2 variable to get output like:

```
"1.1.1.1 - 04.11.21 22:18:23"
```

?

Thx!

Comment: do you **have** to use `awk`? is the input in a string or a file? do you have to performn this formatting for multiple lines of input? is the input (and output) wrapped in a pair of double quotes (ie, are the double quotes part of the 'data from db')?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` and its `strftime`:

```
awk -F '["|]' '{$3=strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", $3); print "\"" $2 " - " $3 "\""}' file
```

or

```
awk -F '["|]' '{$0=strftime("\"" $2 " - %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S\"", $3)}1' file
```

Output:

```
"1.1.1.1 - 04.11.2021 21:18:23"
```

---

See: [9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: I'd be wary of using an unknown string inside the strftime format string.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- data contains literal double quotes as bookends
- data is stored in a variable
- reformatted data to be stored in a new variable with double quotes as bookends

Using some basic `bash` parameter substition/expansion operators:

```
data='"1.1.1.1|1636057103"'
data="${data//\"}"                 # strip double quotes
ip="${data%|*}"                    # break into ip and ...
epoch="${data#*|}"                 # epoch

# build new variable:

printf -v newddata "\"${ip} - '%(%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S)T' @${epoch}" "\""
echo "${newdata}"
```

This generates:

```
"1.1.1.1 - 04.11.21 15:18:23"
```

**NOTE:** the hour component is off from OP's sample output likely due to difference in our timezones